# Abstract client for <ApolloConsumer>

Tags: javascript, apollo, react-apollo, formik

I'm using Formik to validate form data. As additional validation, I check if the user email exists in the database. I have this code working but I don't like having it inline. Is there a better way to write this so validation doesn't have to be inline? I don't understand how to pass the client through.

```
    <Form className="form">
            <ApolloConsumer>
                {client => (
                    <Field className="text-input" type="email" name="email" placeholder="Email" validate={async (value) => {
                        let error

                        const response = await client.query({
                            query: USER_EXISTS,
                            variables: {
                                query: value
                            }
                        })

                        console.log(response.data.userExists)

                        if (response.data.userExists) {
                            error = 'Email taken'
                        }

                        return error
                    }} />
                )}
            </ApolloConsumer>
      <Form>
```

For example, something like this:

```
<ApolloConsumer>
      {client => (
             <Field className="text-input" type="text" name="username" placeholder="Username" validate={this.validateUsername(client)} />
      )}
</ApolloConsumer>


validateUsername = async (value, client) => {
    let error

    const response = await client.query({
        query: USER_EXISTS,
        variables: {
            query: value
        }
    })

    console.log(response.data.userExists)

    if (response.data.userExists) {
        error = 'Username taken'
    }

    return error
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like you need a HOC (High Order Component) is a function that return a component, so to abstract your function you need something like

```
const withApolloClient = (ConnectedComponent) => class extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <ApolloConsumer>
         {client => <ConnectedComponent {...this.props} client={client} />
      </ApolloConsumer>
    );
  }
}
```

once you have setup your `withApolloClient` HOC, so you can use it as follow

```
// create a field component with validation logic
class FieldWithValidationApolloClient extends React.Component {
  async validateUsername() {
    let error;
    const { client, field } = this.props; // get apollo client injected by withApolloClient Hoc
    const { value } = field; // get value from the field


    const response = await client.query({
      query: USER_EXISTS,
      variables: {
        query: value
      }
    })

    console.log(response.data.userExists)

    if (response.data.userExists) {
      error = 'Username taken';
    }

    return error;
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <Field {...this.props} validate={this.validateUsername(client)} />
    );
  }
}
```

And finally just implement your component

```
// import your withApolloClient component file
import withApolloClient from './withApolloClient';
import FieldWithApolloClient from './FieldWithValidationApolloClient';
const FieldWithApollo = withApolloClient(FieldWithApolloClient);

class YourFormComponent extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <form>
        <FieldWithApollo className="text-input" type="text" name="username" placeholder="Username" />
      </form>
    );
  }
}
<form>

</form>
```

> remember that `{...this.props}` will spread all the attributes declare into the tag component

Hope it can help you.

Comment: Thanks! I'm still familiarizing myself with HOCs so I'll try and implement this.